# I'm trying to use Angular JS Timer, and am getting a 'humaniseDuration is not defined' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, controller

I'm using: https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer#requirements

I've bower installed the 'humanize duration' library & have scripted it into my index.html correctly.
I went to the angular-timer.js file and required in 'humanize duration' - it didn't make a difference.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why did you 'required in humanize duration' in angular-timer.js? I would not suggest joining 3rd party libraries. Include them in your index and use the pieces you need on your view to get the desired effect. Also please try to include a reproducible sample, like on Plunkr.

Comment: Did get any solution above  question. I'm also getting same error @Rachel